# Git subtree workflow

Tags: git, git-workflow, git-subtree

In my current project I'm using an open source forum ( https://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden ). I was planning on doing something like this :

```
git remote add vanilla_remote https://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden.git
git checkout -b vanilla vanilla_remote/master
git checkout master
git read-tree --prefix=vanilla -u vanilla
```

This way I can make change into the vanilla folder (like changing config) and commit it to my master branch and I can also switch into my vanilla branch to fetch updates. My problem is when I try to merge the branch together

```
git checkout vanilla
git pull
git checkout master
git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit vanilla
git commit -a -m "update commit"
```

The problem is that the "update commit" goes on top of my commits and "overwrite" my change. I would rather like to have my commits replay on top of the update. Is there a simple way to do that? I'm not very good in git so maybe this is the wrong approach. Also, I really don't want to mix my history with the vanilla history.

Comment: I have the same problem, I just want to do this (from http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging): "All the changes from your Rack project are merged in and ready to be committed locally. You can also do the opposite — make changes in the rack subdirectory of your master branch and then merge them into your rack_branch branch later to submit them to the maintainers or push them upstream." And THEN do the merge command. They mention it but there is no sample command.

Comment: @ernipiggy Did you find a way to push from a subtree?

Comment: @abel I tried to explain it below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finished up with this scheme:

1. Work on my *development* branch touching files from the *subtree*.
2. Update the *subtree* branch with squashed *development* commits:

> git merge -s subtree --squash --no-commit *development*

Update the *subtree* branch with its remote repository.

Update *development* with squashed *subtree* commits:

> git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit *subtree*

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to work with subtrees, you probably want to use [`git subtree`](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). It provides a somewhat more user-friendly interface to this sort of thing, including merge/pull commands to merge in a subtree (squashing is optional) and split/push commands to split back apart changes to a subtree and send them back to its own repo.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit vanilla
```

will not "overwrite" your change. I am hoping by "update commit" you mean the commit you did after the subtree merge since it has `--no-commit` and will not commit by itself.

Comment: Yes exactly. Still, from that point the only way I can get the correct behavior is to rebase -i and to push back that commit under my changes and I don't really like that..

Answer (score 0):

I too am not a git master (see what I did there ;-) ) ... however, I think you may want to look at the rebase command:

http://book.git-scm.com/4_rebasing.html

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how the rebase command could be of any help because the two branch don't share any common "base".